# Regex expression for any times any character between two set of literals

Tags: regex, string-search

Hi a am new to regex and programming. I in a textual file want to search any thing (all characters) between first occurrences of two literal namely- 'html' and 'http'. I have tried lot of expression, but no success. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try: `html(.*?)http`

Comment: sory, yes it searches the required string . but i want  excluding 'html' n 'http'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this regex,

```
(?<=html).*?(?=http)
```

Use `s` switch to make dot to match newlines also.

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=html)` Positive lookbehind is used. It matches all the characters after the word `html`.
- `.*?` It matches any character zero or more times. `?` after `*` makes the regex engine to match the shortest possibility.
- `(?=http)` Positive lookahead. Matches any characters before `http`.

Comment: can u suggest me some source or easily available book for using n learning regex for beginners

Comment: see http://www.regular-expressions.info/ . If you have doubts in regex then don't hesitate to ask me by dropping a message below to my answer.

Comment: +1 Good answer. @user3528086: Accept the answer by clicking on tick mark on top-left of this answer.

Comment: i am trying to accept this as my ans, but this site tells me 'after 2min u can accept this as ur ans'

Comment: ya before this i went to regular-expressions.info . but there example are a bit difficult to comprehend for beginner like me.